# Write Request metric

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I'm currently using 1-node cluster with DataStax Opscenter 5.2.1 (Cassandra 2.2.3) installed on Windows.

There is not too much data is sent to the cluster, and here is the graph (last 20 minutes) of write requests that I can see in Opscenter. The graph looks normal and expected for me:
[write_requests(20min)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMHP1.png)

However, when I've switched the data range to last 1 hour, as turns out there were much more write requests (according to cluste(max) line): 
[write_requests(1h)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhgQx.png)

I'm confused, could someone clarify what cluster(max) means in my case? Why these values are so big in comparison with cluster(total) or cluster(min)?

Comment: Update:

fixed this by rolling back to the previous version of DataStax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first graph (20 minute) uses an average. The 1h graph will have 3 lines - min per sample, average, and max per sample.

What you're likely seeing is that something (perhaps opscenter itself) is doing a flood of writes, about 700/second for a few seconds, and on the 20 minute graph it gets averaged out, but with the min/max lines, you'll see the outliers.

Comment: Thanks Jeff,

I've rolled back to the previous stable version of DataStax (5.2.1 and 2.1.11 Cassandra) and now the graphs look normal, even cluster(max) line. 
So, probably this is a bug in a development version of DataStax Opscenter (http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra/) or they indeed included some additional opscenter writes in these graphs, as you said.

Comment: For the record, this isn't necessarily a bug - could just be a new feature/rollup. If it's not causing you problems, you can just leave it as-is. 700 writes for a few seconds isn't a big deal for Cassandra -most nodes can handle 40-50k operations per second under normal circumstances.